# Unable to compile class for JSP using TagSuppot

Tags: jsp, servlets, taglib, custom-tags

i am trying to usse my own tag using tag support. But when i load my page the following error occurs:

> HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP

Taglib included like this: 
***<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="customtags" %>***

What am i doing wrong?

```html
<jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>customtags</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>WEB-INF/tags/custom.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>ctg</short-name>
    <uri>customtags</uri>
    <tag>
        <name>info-time</name>
        <tag-class>by.epam.customtags.HelloTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

```
public class HelloTag extends TagSupport {
@Override
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    String time = "<hr/>Time : <b> " + gc.getTime() + " </b><hr/>";
    String locale = "Locale : <b> " + Locale. getDefault() + " </b><hr/> ";
    try {
        JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
        out.write(time + locale);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new JspException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return SKIP_BODY;
}

@Override
public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
    return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
}
```

### UPDATE: solved by adding SupressWarnings("serial")

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
   <jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
    <short-name>ctg</short-name>
    <uri>customtags</uri>
    <tag>
        <name>info-time</name>
        <tag-class>by.epam.customtags.HelloTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
    </tag>
</taglib>


And use direct reference in the jsp as

<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="WEB-INF/tags/custom.tld" %>
```

Comment: gives me the same error... And also underlines <jsp-version> with red as incorrect tag

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! The problem was that i add

> SupressWarnings("serial")

before HelloTag class